# View memcache data in admin console?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

Since I insert data in `memcached` via my application, and didn't set **Namespace** I am expecting that the its namespace is default. When viewing in admin console I leave namespace blank but I can't find the value.

[image: Memcached Viewer Screen Shoot]

Comment: Most likely the value is not in Memcache anymore. As you can see in screenshot, the key "airGHelper1" also doesn't have a namespace and hence "" as Namespace. So the values are stored in blank namespace properly

Comment: As far I know it is memchance. Coz I store like 
`keycache.put(key, entity);`
which **keycache** declare as 
`public static MemcacheService keycache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();`

And when I retrieve as,
` (Entity) keycache.get(key);`
the data still exists. The only thing is Im not sure how to store the cache with namespace.

Comment: In your code is the =key= variable of type =String=?  (To match the "Java String" option you selected in the Admin Console.)